# Vue 3 migrate broken scope by key

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I migrate *v-for* from vue 2 to vue 3 and get different behavior.

Main component render array of two items to child component **with scope KEY**:

```
let items = computed(() => [  { subarray:[] }, { subarray:[] }  ]);

<div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
   <X :item="item"></X>
</div>
```

Component "X":

```
    <div v-for="i in item.subarray">
       {{ i }}
    </div>

const props = defineProps({
    item: Object,
});

function add(){
   props.item.subarray.push("abc");
}
```

But then i add new item to subarray in **SECOND** instance of component 'X', item **ADDED TO FIRST** instance of component X.
What is problem ?

This code in vue 2 work fine, then i add item in second instance of component X i get right show in second instance.

Comment: It seems that you only posted the codes for ```vue3```, could you add the codes of ```vue2``` that you say works fine to your question?

Comment: Seems like a vue3 proxy issue.  send the item you want to add to the parent using `emit`, and let the parent add it to the subarray.  This will also adhere to the 'do not modify your props' rule.